# Prime numbers program error (MASM)

Tags: assembly, primes, division, masm

Having a slight error in this program. It's a simple program that allows the user to input a number higher than 2 and determine if it's prime or not. It works fine expect for the numbers of 3 and 4. 3 is said to be not a prime and 4 is a prime. I'm simply showing the code for the calculations.

```
;ecx = divisor, esi = max divisor, edx = remainder, eax = quotient

mov ebx, eax
shr eax, 1
mov esi, eax   ;Max divisor value
mov ecx, 1

 isPrime:
      inc ecx
      cmp ecx, esi
      je Prime

      mov edx, 0
      mov eax, ebx
      div ecx
      cmp edx, 0
      jz NotPrime

      jmp isPrime
```

I'm not sure if the `shr` might have something to do with the error. Any explanations? I'm trying to avoid making jumps just for those values.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`je Prime` is wrong. The value of `ESI` is the half of `EAX` (rounded down). If `EAX` is 3, then `ESI` will become 1. `ECX` starts effectively with 2 (`mov ecx, 1` `inc ecx`). So it will loop over the whole 32 bit range before it will be equal to `ESI`. When `ECX` becomes 3 then the loop will break to `NotPrime`.

If `EAX`==4, the loop will break to `Prime` at once: the first `ECX` is 2 and `ESI` is 2.

Remedy: Change `je Prime` to `ja Prime`.